# zsh split directory into array

Tags: arrays, zsh

I'm trying to get an array containing the full current directory path in zsh. I'm currently using

```
local pwd="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
pwd_list=(${(s:/:)pwd})
```

Which works except for one problem, it treats the starting / as a directory split too. I'd like my array to be like

- /
- usr
- lib
- php

instead of

- usr
- lib
- php

I can see 2 ways of doing this but I'm unaware of how to do either in zsh. The first idea is to simple do a push and force a new element to the beginning (after the split).

The second, would be to alter the split to ignore the first / when parsing.

How can I resolve this to get an accurate directory path with minimal overhead into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you really need the first `/`? Assuming you're using a script to use the results of that, can't you just `cd /` to just start from there?

Anyways... is this what you want?

```
local pwd="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
pwd_list=(${(s:/:)pwd})
pwd_list=('/' $pwd_list)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't get a notification, weird. The reason I wanted this was because I'm using an array to run scripts, some for parsing directory paths, and some for display data to the user.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will do the wrong thing if the `$HOME`-to-`~` substitution happens: the result will be ( / ~ foo bar ).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're thinking about it slightly wrong.  If you split "/usr/lib/php" on "/", you should get four elements, the first of which is an empty string.  If you join those array elements back together with "/", you get the original path.  Trying to think of the first element of "/" means you're treating the splitting inconsistently, which will make everything else harder.

So the problem really is that you're only getting three elements instead of four: the empty first element is getting dropped.  You can fix that by quoting, like this:

```
local pwd="${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
pwd_list=( "${(s:/:)pwd}" )
```

(The extra space next to the outer parentheses isn't necessary, but it makes it a little easier to read.)  You can even combine that into one expression:

```
pwd_list=( "${(s:/:)${PWD/#$HOME/~}}" )
```